# Añadir funcionalidad Code Snippet en las preguntas

Tags: soporte, stack-snippets

Estuve buscando la manera para generar una nueva pregunta, usando el code-snippet como se muestra en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762009/pulsing-heart-css-animation), pero no encuentro información en el sitio Meta de Stack Exchange.

¿Esta opción se encuentra disponible en SO en Español? y, si es así; ¿cómo puedo agregar el code-snippet en las preguntas y respuestas?

---

Hace algunas semanas; hice la siguiente [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2980/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-caracteres-codificados-de-un-archivo-generado-en-pdf-usando-jspdf) *"la cual contiene un archivo de prueba para descargar"*, sin embargo, creo que no muchas personas accederían a descargar dichos archivos y en su lugar, prefieren ver el código fuente y funcionando tal como se puede apreciar en la primera pregunta enlazada.

Comment: Eso sería perfecto incluyera más lenguajes, php, c#, java etc..

Comment: @Webserveis, puede generar una pregunta con la etiqueta `feature-request` en el Meta de Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Si**, se encuentra disponible desde el inicio.

## Presiona <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

#### <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> o el botón que hay para ello en el editor de pregunta (o respuesta):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez dentro, tienes una caja para el HTML, otra para el CSS y otra para JavaScript, muy similar a http://jsfiddle.net, aunque con menos opciones. (ej. actualmente no soporta SCSS)

#### Tienes ademas los siguientes botones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Correr: Ejecuta el ejemplo en dentro del propio editor.
- Ordenar: Aplica reglas de identación a todo el código.
- Insertar en la publicación: pues sale del editor y el ejemplo quede como code snippet en el post.
- Restablecer: Borra todo el snippet.
- Ocultar fragmento de forma predeterminada: Si marcas este *checkbox*, el fragmento no sera visible en la pregunta/respuesta hasta que lo expandas. Es decir que solo sera visible que hay un fragmento y la opción de expandirlo pero no así el código.

Una vez que haz salido del editor de code snippet (presionando "Insertar en la publicación") para volver a editarlo debes buscar este enlace debajo del boton "Ejecutar fragmento de código".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que parece falta traducir :S

Suerte!

Comment: **"edit the above snippet"** Esta cadena no está en Transifex por eso no se ha traducido.

Comment: Gracias. Ahora he publicado mi [pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3211/componente-datepicker-api-no-es-consistente-con-la-selecci%C3%B3n-de-fechas) y haré lo posible para agregar futuras preguntas y respuestas usando esta funcionalidad (muy útil, por cierto).